# Scraping first result from duckduckgo in rvest in r

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm scraping profile pages of fighters for a personal project in data analytics. However, sometimes the profile URL is not available from the site I'm scraping. In that case I'd like to search the person on Duckduckgo and scrape the first result using the Rvest package for R. I'm having trouble selecting the correct node. This is no problem on most sites, but somehow sites like Google and Duckduckgo are different.

This is the code I have so far.

```
if (length(f2.url) == 0) tryCatch({
baseurl <- 'https://duckduckgo.com/?q='
query <- fight.details$f2.name[i]
queryurl <- gsub(" ","+", paste0(baseurl, query, "in 
fightmetric.com/fighter-details"))

f2.urla <- read_html(queryurl) %>% 
html_nodes('#r1-0 > div > div.result__extras > div') %>% 
html_text(trim = TRUE) %>% as.character()
```

I didn't have any problem selecting nodes from other sites, but somehow Google and Duckduckgo seem different.

How can I achieve this?